# Phospholipid movement in cell membranes

Tags: biochemistry, cell-membrane, lipids

What causes phospholipids to flow so quickly in cell membranes? In Biology by Cambell et al. they state that a phospholipids can travel up to 2 micrometers per second. Is that a random movement or has anyone found that phospholipids have a current?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be charge considerations in the movement of molecules in the lipid membrane. There is also a consideration that some species of phospholipids will migrate to [portions of the membrane with sharper or smoother curvature](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0005273614001850).

Waves of electrical potential can propagate along a lipid bilayer as well, which is very important to nerve axons and extended structures like that.

In general though the membrane is held together by vanDerWaals forces like other non-polar solvents.  As such, the movements of lipids and proteins and other amphipathic molecules in the membrane are still largely Brownian (random) in the 2D surface of the membrane.